# Components as custom blots in Quill editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

I'm about to use components (Angular/Vue/React or else) as custom building blocks that will be embedded in the editor:

```
class FooBlot extends BlockEmbed {
  static create(val) {
    const node = super.create();

    React.render(<FooComponent ...>, node);

    node.contentEditable = false;
    return node;
  }
}

FooBlot.tagName = 'DIV';
FooBlot.className = 'foo';
FooBlot.blotName = 'foo';
```

Which is inserted to as `quill.insertEmbed(..., 'foo', val)`.

So it is expected that

```
<div class="foo" data-bar="Bar"></div>
```

will be rendered to

```
<div class="foo" data-bar="Bar">
  <div>
    <div class="bar">Bar</div>
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

in editor.

But I'd like to get `<div class="foo" data-bar="Bar"></div>` without nested DOM as editor value, because nested nodes are there only for preview purposes.

Another problem I'm trying to solve is that the components are expected to be un-editable, but setting `contentEditable` adds `contenteditable` attribute to `<div class="foo">` which is not needed in the output.

How is this kind of clean up supposed to be performed on editor value?

Comment: What's your FooComponent look like? It would seem it is inserting the empty div. If you want something to be uneditable within a contenteditable div, the only way is to make it contenteditable=false. Not sure why you mean by "needed in the output" or "value" in ...performed on editor value.

Comment: FooComponent is not really relevant here, it's there only to show that the blot provides nested DOM which should be shown in WYSIWYG preview but be discarded in editor value. Regarding 'value', it's resulting value of the editor, a string (like in 'input value'). It is supposed to be submitted as a part of the form and stored in DB.

Comment: Sorry was traveling a bit. I'm still not 100% on value -- I suppose another question to clarify this is: How would you get what you are referring to as the editor value? Is it node.innerHTML, quill.getText(), quill.getContents() or something else?

Comment: I'd expect it to behave similarly to regular form inputs and provide `innerHTML` as something that is percieved as input 'value'. I previously used third-party Quill component for Angular, and I believe it used `innerHTML` by default, just because HTML string value is usually expected from WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: No regular form inputs I know of provide `innerHTML` as its value. Which one are you thinking of?

Comment: Did you find a good solution for your problem? I'm trying to achieve something similar: I want to replace a custom html tag by a component but I don't want to put in the HTML the rendered component (only the custom html tag).

Comment: @MaximeChéramy Sadly, no. I don't remember how I exactly worked around it. Most likely I postprocessed editor value and cleaned up rendered components.